# How to change syles of a webpage inside iframe from parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to load a webpage on an iframe and then change some styles from the parent page through javascript. The webpage to load on an iframe isn't on my domain. I mean, it can be some random page on the web. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) explains it very well for you.